# Opendirectoryd too many corpses being created

Tags: macos

I had this problem when I was on High Sierra, so I copied my files on a hard drive and installed El Capitan. I'm just curious now — was that error recoverable? What I did: reset VRAM, reset SMC, repair startup disc, reinstall MacOS, fix file system and nothing helped.

Comment: Does [Crashed: too many corpses being created — How to Recover High Sierra](https://robinmonks.com/2018/01/crashed-too-many-corpses-being-created-how-to-recover-high-sierra/) help?

Comment: @GrahamMiln  Nope, still was stuck in boot loop

Answer (score 11):

This solution worked for my MacBook Pro: https://mrsystems.co.uk/blogs/news/too-many-corpses-being-created

Steps from the article:

> 1. boot and hold cmd-R to start up from macOS Recovery
> 2. If Filevault is on, mount the disk with Disk Utility and password
> 3. Run these two in Terminal
> 4. `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/caches/opendirectory`
> 5. `mv ./mbr_cache ./mbr_cache-old`
> 6. Restart

Comment: **If you are using the non-apple keyboard then you will not able to go in Recovery mode So, Please use Apple keyboard**